Given a closed set in a preordered metric space. Does its minimum value always exist?
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and also $(X,\le)$ is a preordered set. If given a subset $E\subset X$ and $E$ is a closed set, can we always find the minimum value $\beta$ of $E$, such that $\forall x\in E,x\ge\beta$ ?
This question may be kind of stupid, but I am a little confused.

This does appear as a stupid question... But should it still exist (maybe for new learners)?

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric with the usual order 'less than or equal to'. Take $E=(-\infty, 0]$.

Typo in the definition of $E$.

What's the typo?

$(\infty,0]$ or $(-\infty,0]$?

yeah i correct it
